# Is there a way to load "Sign In With Google" using require/import?

Tags: google-signin

In the documentation they suggest inserting a script tag:
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/client-library

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

However, I'd like to utilize Webpack's async imports and as such I'd like to import/require the code via an npm package. Is there an npm package somewhere for this or am I forced to include it using a script tag?

Something like this:

```js
const google = await import('x')
google.accounts.id.initialize(IdConfiguration)
```